# Least amount of pairwise distances needed to embed $k$ points positions in the plane (and more generally, $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I was wondering about how much distance information is needed to embed a certain amount of points within $\Bbb R^2$. I've tried to check manually, and it seems to me that $2\cdot k-3$ pairwise distances are needed to fully determine $k$ points' position in $\Bbb R^2$, but I have no clue whether this is actually true.

What I know is that a triangle can be fully determined by $3$ pairwise distances (thus determining the position of $3$ points) and that a quadrilateral can be fully determined by $5$ distances ($4$ sides $+ 1$ diagonal, thus determining the position of $4$ points) but I am unsure about larger, concave and convex, polygons. I am also unsure if the minimum amount of distances depend on which distances are chosen.

- Also, what would the relationship between  the (least) number of pairwise distances needed to embed $k$ points in $\Bbb R^n$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a large literature on this kind of question.
See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(mechanical) .
In general 2k-3 distances determine a k-point configuration in the plane
up to a finite choice; likewise in 3-space start with all six distances
in a tetrahedron and then add three for each new point, so 3k-6.
But there are many wrinkles, exceptional configurations, and open questions.

Comment: I have voted to close. 1) There are too many questions here, most of them not even using question marks (as indicated by the “also” before the one question with a question mark). 2) There is no evidence of research before posting. 3) It partially duplicates questions like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346979/distribution-of-pairwise-distances/347177. I’m open to questions of this sort that are better chosen, better punctuated, better researched, and better delineated, but this isn’t it yet.